# Use of "too ... to" in a certain sentence

Tags: adverbs, quantifiers

While I was doing a quiz on an English grammar website, I saw this sentence

> I do not have (too - enough) much time to prepare dinner

and "too" as the correct answer. But what I've learned and what is explained on the website, is "too ... to" means more than necessary. I thought it was a mistake, but I've found many sentences like it on Google. Can you explain me its use in this sentence, please?

Comment: Correct answer to what question?

Comment: It was a MCQ. And this is the answered sentence. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @MohamedSDarwish It's an odd locution. I would expect *I don't have enough time to prepare dinner*, but that leaves out the *much*. The *to* isn't a factor. It's just part of the infinitive complement. You could rephrase *I do not have too much time for preparing dinner*. *Too much* means an excess, so here "more than enough" or "more than necessary". Do you remember the other choices?

Comment: @deadrat Suggests good question for *single-word request*.

Comment: The other choice was "enough"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a neutral situation, the sentence would read 'I don't have enough time...' However, the use of '*too* + much' is intended to convey that there is some criticality or seriousness related to the situation. Perhaps he is cooking for his mother-in-law or he wishes to be excused on time from his work meeting, or both!

It is less formal and quite commonly used.

Comment: Yes. The difference seems to be in degree of stress in stating "I don't have enough time to prepare dinner".

Answer (score 0):

*Too much* or *very much* are common. In negative contexts, they just mean *much*.

1. *I don't have enough time.*

You're having Pop-Tarts for dinner.

2. *I don't have much time.*

This might mean: I probably have enough time, but it's going to be close.

Or it might mean: I am about to try to get you to cook dinner tonight.

3. *I don't have very much time.*
4. *I don't have a whole lot of time.*
5. *I don't have too much time.*

All virtually identical to 2. If there's a difference, it's that these are logically a bit weaker. In 5 the literal meaning is that I do not have an excessive amount of time—not much of a statement.

The combination of negation + intensifier makes the meaning subtle. In a positive context, things are easier. You can't use *much* by itself (*I have much time* is wrong) and *too much* literally means an excessive amount (*I have too much time to myself* is fine).

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

"I don't have enough time" => I can't do it, it would take longer than the time I have available.

"I don't have too much time" => I can possibly do it if I move fast, but it will take all the time I have got, there will be no margin to spare.